# Merging two polylines with programming?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, .net, line

We are currently working on a project where we have to merge sections (polylines) to a route, but the big question is how to do this. We have currently tried adding those two as segmentcollections but it gives some rather wicked results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [ITopologicalOperator.Union](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/componenthelp/index.html#//0023000003w2000000) method called on one of those polylines, passing the second one as its parameter. As long as the two polylines' endpoints meet, this approach should solve your problem.

EDIT: when performing union on multiple geometries (more than two), [ITopologicalOperator.ConstructUnion](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/componenthelp/index.html#/ConstructUnion_Method/0023000003vn000000/) is more efficient. You would call this method on an empty (freshly created) Polyline, passing an enumeration of all the polylines. This enumeration can be a GeometryBag instance as it implements IEnumGeometry.

Comment: I just switched back from   `ITopologicalOperator.ConstructUnion` to `ITopologicalOperator.Union` because the merged geometry wasn't correct --vertices were moved (looked almost like the line was generalized except the vertex count didn't change).

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use MergeGeometries from [IConstructMerge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000000vm000000) interface.

I guess even that can solve the above issue!